# How to initiate manually an animation in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation

I have a prefab and I want to control when an animation is initiated. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I have already created the animation clip, the animator component for the prefab, and the animator controller. The animation works, when I enter play mode in the unity editor (it plays automatically), but I want to control when the animation occurs when providing input (such as pressing on the space bar or clicking on the prefab).

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You'd either use an Animation component's Play() method (disabling playOnAwake), or an Animator component's SetTrigger() method with a transition to your animation keyed to that trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to call on an animation at will, the object must start in an empty state. To initiate an animation get the animator component for the object and call Play("stateName") on it. Remember to revert back to the empty so that the playable state can be replayed later

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to refer to Unity Documentation for these kind of questions.

What you want to do can be achieved by using [Animation States](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/class-State.html) and [Transitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/class-Transition.html).

Basically, you need to create an empty state in the **Prefab's** Animator Controller and set it to *Default* (Orange color). And create a transition from this empty state to the state which contains your light animation then set the condition for transition (Which could be bool indicating an user input).